# Suma dinámica de inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy generando inputs dinámicamente, que serán las notas de un alumno. De tal forma que me queda algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De manera que, si yo aprieto el botón nueva nota, se me añadirá un input nuevo para poder añadir la nota.

En mi código html creo el botón de agregar una nueva nota y hago un div, que este div posteriormente será en el que añadiremos los inputs.

```
<form id="formulario" method="get" action="notas-variable.php">
    <button id="agregar">Nueva Nota</button>
    <div id="dinamic" name="dinamic"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar"/>
</form>
```

En mi código javascript tengo un evento de agregar los inputs, eliminarlos y actualizarlos:

```
const contenedor = document.querySelector("#dinamic");
const btnAgregar = document.querySelector("#agregar");


let total=1;

btnAgregar.addEventListener('click',e =>{
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML=`<label>`+(total++)+`</label> - <input type="text" name="notas[]" placeholder="Nota" required><button onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button>`;
    contenedor.appendChild(div);
})

const eliminar=(e)=>{
    const divPadre = e.parentNode;
    contenedor.removeChild(divPadre);
    actualizarContador();
}

const actualizarContador=()=>{
    let divs = contenedor.children;
    total = 1;
    for(let i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
        divs[i].childen[0].innerHTML=total++;
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que ahorá necesito sumar los valores de los inputs, de tal forma que pase ese valor de la suma y la longitud de el div(los inputs que hay) a php.

He intentado algo así, pero me salé que el array es nulo:

```
<?php
$notas = $_GET['dinamic'] ?? null;
echo var_dump($notas);
?>
```

Comment: que pasa si lo intentas con `$_GET["notas"]`?

Comment: Listo, era aquello! muchas gracias